# Mocking extension function in Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, kotlin, powermock

How to mock Kotlin extension function using Mockito or PowerMock in tests? Since they are resolved statically should they be tested as static method calls or as non static?

Comment: Just like in Java, you want to avoid static methods like that. Static methods should usually be used as simple util functions. Extension functions are like static methods, so they should only be used as simple util functions. These functions should be so simple it is not needed or worth to mock them.

Comment: can you provide what have you tried till now?

Comment: Just wondering: are you still waiting for other answers; or is there something I could do to make my answer accept-worthy?

Answer (score 68):

I think **MockK** can help you.

It supports mocking *extension functions* too.

You can use it to mock object-wide extensions:

```
data class Obj(val value: Int)

class Ext {
    fun Obj.extensionFunc() = value + 5
}

with(mockk<Ext>()) {
    every {
        Obj(5).extensionFunc()
    } returns 11

    assertEquals(11, Obj(5).extensionFunc())

    verify {
        Obj(5).extensionFunc()
    }
}
```

If you extension is a module-wide, meaning that it is declared in a file (not inside `class`), you should mock it in this way:

```
data class Obj(val value: Int)

// declared in File.kt ("pkg" package)
fun Obj.extensionFunc() = value + 5

mockkStatic("pkg.FileKt")

every {
    Obj(5).extensionFunc()
} returns 11

assertEquals(11, Obj(5).extensionFunc())

verify {
    Obj(5).extensionFunc()
}
```

By adding `mockkStatic("pkg.FileKt")` line with the name of a package and file where extension is declared (`pkg.File.kt` in the example).

In jvm environments you can replace the class name with a function reference:

```
mockkStatic(Obj::extensionFunc)
```

Note that this will mock the whole pkg.FileKt class, and not just extensionFunc.

This syntax also applies for extension properties:

```
val Obj.squareValue get() = value * value

mockkStatic(Obj::squareValue)
```

More info can be found here: [web site](https://mockk.io/#extension-functions) and [github](https://github.com/mockk/mockk)

Comment: does this work when the extension function has arguments? Verify seems to fail due to mismatching arguments (weirdly it seems to expect another argument, of type equal to the class you're extending)

Comment: Works prefectly, thanks! Note when using *verify* you need to use the one from Mockk library and not from Mockito. Since I had both in the same file, I solved it by creating import alias: `import io.mockk.verify as verifyMockk`

Comment: This did not work for me, but a slightly different way did (adapted to the example):
every {
    any<Obj>().extensionFunc()
} returns 11

looks silly because now the result does not depend on parameters, but in my use-case it didn't have to and the other way was throwing errors.

Comment: You can also use `mockkStatic(Obj::extensionFunction.declaringKotlinFile.qualifiedName!!)` instead of specifying the file name as string. That will prevent strange errors, when the file is renamed or moved.

Comment: @Benjamin Can you explain how to write this mockkStatic with example? Say my mock abstract class is Context, the extension function is getActivity() and it is in file ActivityExtension.kt whose jvm name is ActivityUtil

Comment: @Terry you can write something like this: `mockkStatic(Context::getActivity.declaringKotlinFile.qualifiedName!!) { your test code }`. In your test-code you can either mock `getActivity` for a concrete instance `every { myContext.getActivity() } returns ...` or for any instance `every { any<Context>().getActivity() } returns ...`.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, Mockito knows **nothing** Kotlin specific language constructs. In the end, Mockito will have a look **into** the byte code. Mockito is only able to understand what it finds there and what looks like a Java language construct.

Meaning: to be really sure, you might want to use [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) to deassemble the compiled classfiles to identify the exact names/signatures of the methods you want to mock.

And obviously: when that method is *static*, you have to user PowerMock, or JMockit; if not, you should prefer to with Mockito.

From a java point of view, you simply avoid mocking static stuff; but of course, things get really interesting, now that different languages with different ideas/concepts come together.

Comment: just for the next person, extension function signatures in java: `class FilenameKt { public static ReturnType extensionName(Receiver receiver, Params otherParams)...`

Answer (score 9):

Instance extension functions can be stubbed and verified like this with the help of mockito-kotlin:

```kotlin
data class Bar(thing: Int)

class Foo {
   fun Bar.bla(anotherThing: Int): Int { ... }
}

val bar = Bar(thing = 1)
val foo = mock<Foo>()

with(foo) {
  whenever(any<Bar>().bla(any()).doReturn(3)
}

verify(foo).apply {
  bar.bla(anotherThing = 2)
}
```

Comment: So you have to wrap the extension function in a class?

Answer (score 3):

I use **mockk** library.

For extension file write java name, like this:

```
@file:JvmName(name = "ExtensionUtils")

package myproject.extension

...
```

And for fast codding I created file with different extension mocks:

```
object FastMock {

    fun extension() = mockkStatic("myproject.extension.ExtensionUtils")

    fun listExtension() = mockkStatic("myproject.extension.ListExtensionUtils")

}
```

In test call this:

```
FastMock.listExtension()
every { itemList.move(from, to) } returns Unit
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Mockk](https://mockk.io/) library,

Given a top level (meaning not declared in a class) extension method in the `ContextExt.kt` file such as:

```
Context.doSomething(param1: Int, param2: String = "default") : Int {
   // Does something that wouldn't work in your test environment
}
```

To mock it, we can do the following:

```
MyTestClass {
   companion object {
       private const val MOCKED_VALUE = 10
   }
   ...

   @Before
   fun before() {
      mockkStatic("com.my.package.ContextExtKt")
      every { any<Context>().doSomething(any(), any()) } returns MOCKED_VALUE
   }
}
```

A couple things to be careful about :

1. The argyou provide to mockkStatic is the package name as declared on the 1st line of your file + the filename + "Kt". For instance for the file `ContextExt.kt` in package `com.my.package` you need : `mockkStatic("com.my.package.ContextExtKt")`
2. Provide all the args to the extension method you're trying to mock, even if they have default values. Either use specific values if you need, otherwise use `any()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use:

```kotlin
mockkStatic(YourClass::extensionFunction)
every { any<YourClass>().extensionFunction() } returns YOUR_MOCKED_DATA
```

e.g

```kotlin
fun String.doSomething() = "SOMETHING"

@Test
fun `test extension functions`() {
    mockkStatic(String::doSomething)
    every { any<String>().doSomething() } returns YOUR_MOCKED_DATA
}
```