# how to stub kotlin map function | unittest

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, extension-methods, extension-function

i want to stub kotlin's map extension function in my unit test. couldn't find any proper solution on internet to do that.

ctually i have put empty blocks inside curly brackets but it seems like this is not the way that i should do.

**here is what i have been trying so far:**

```
whenever(trainWorkoutResult.exerciseSections.map {}).thenReturn(trainSections)
```

**here is the error that i got:**

```
no answer found for: 

    LegacyDataMapper(#4).mappingSectionsToRecordedExerciseDataModels(Mock for List, hashCode: 1199894489)
```

any idea?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382540/mocking-extension-function-in-kotlin

Comment: You cannot and should not.  You can stub the function you pass _to_ `map`, but not `map` itself, and a good thing too.

Comment: ty all <3 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

solved it like that:

```
 with(mockk<List<Section>>()) {
                every {
                    trainWorkoutResult.exerciseSections
                } returns (listOf(Section(12, "123", emptyList())))
            }
```

inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382540/mocking-extension-function-in-kotlin) question.

ps: i am using `mockk` library